# Computing algebraic entropy

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Could you recommend any reference for computing algebraic entropy?

Here algebraic entropy is defiened as $\lim_{n \to \infty}\log (deg (f^n))^{1/n}$ for a rational map $f $.

I saw that there are three method for computing, Heuristic, Blow-up, and Derived map .(https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://maths.dur.ac.uk/lms/105/talks/1003vial.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjB-_qT2tTcAhWE-mEKHe_BADkQFjAEegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw0ejXXEews8rzd94vpn2Ol0)

I want to find the original reference about these method or other methods.

By the way, are there any result about a lower bound for algebraic entropy?